# Swivel adaptor for screw bits

Tags: tools

I am looking for a swivel adapter that will allow the turning of screws at an angle.
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can find the adapter you need with the 1/4 socket wrenches. Try this: https://www.mscdirect.com/browse/tnpla/41411653. In small spaces it's much safer than the flex shafts (they tend to loop back on themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [flexible shaft](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RYOBI-11-in-Flexible-Shaft-Bit-Holder-A10FB1G/205193137):
[image]

This should work at any angle, though since it is flexible the speed will be limited compared to a rigid adapter.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: "flexible shaft" at the top of the answer is a link to Home Depot. But you can also Google: **flexible shaft drill bit** and find plenty of others.

Comment: I do not think a 11 inch shaft will work. It is probably too long for my application.

Comment: This looks like it will work. https://www.amazon.com/AUTOTOOLHOME-Flexible-Extension-Ratchet-Screwdriver/dp/B01M7N041K/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=1%2F4%22+Hex+Shank+Flexible+Shaft+Drill+Bit+Holder&qid=1564165232&s=gateway&sr=8-7